# "Open Declaration", etc., pops up "The resource is not on a include path of a javascript project" in a Nodeclipse MEAN project

Tags: javascript, eclipse, include-path, mean-stack, nodeclipse

In Nodeclipse, "Open Declaration" "Open Type Hierarchy" and "Open Call Hierarchy" all seem to always pop up a message saying "The resource is not on a include path of a javascript project". This issue was encountered with an existing MEAN stack project (available at pactvote.com) that I'm just getting started on. This is my first time working with MEAN and Nodeclipse. If you want to try and replicate this with the above-mentioned project, you may have to increase memory usage in eclipse.ini and implement the workaround described at https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/159 . I downloaded Enide-Studio-2014-011-20140228-macosx-cocoa-x86_64. The only plugin installed is MercurialEclipse 2.1. I thought of trying to fiddle with the build path, but when I right-clicked on the project and moused over Build Path it said "No actions available." I didn't see anything to change in the project properties either.

The project was created with WebStorm.

Why is this issue occurring and how do I fix it?

Comment: This is complex issue caused by combination of factors. 1) Try to install Enide Studio plugings into latest Eclipse (for .17 there is only Windows package). 2) Try to investigate what particular npm package causes hangs/crashes in JSDT. When issue is reproducible, it can be raise on Eclipse bugs.

Comment: Thanks but I don't have a Windows system to do that with and I don't know how to do 2). BTW, (I learnt after posting the question that) the project's vagrantfile needs revision so installation on non-ubuntu systems won't work right now; I'll add another comment when that's done.

Comment: Have you solved? What was the problem?

Comment: The vagrantfile was revised. (I think it was made with an older version).